# How do I set my new secret key base for Sidekiq in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, capistrano, sidekiq

I am using the following gems in my application.

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-unique-jobs'
gem 'sidekiq-cron'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', github: 'seuros/capistrano-sidekiq'
```

I recently started using `activerecord-session_store` and in the process I remember having to update my `secret_key_base` for my application.  Now when I try to make changes through the SideKiq admin panel I always get a blank white page that says "forbidden".  I'm guessing that my session is not being shared correctly? How can I set up SideKiq to use the same secret_key_base as my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to share Rails' secret key base with Sidekiq web interface:

```
Sidekiq::Web.set :session_secret, Rails.application.secrets[:secret_key_base]
```

Comment: where exactly do i put this?

Comment: Oh! Sorry I forgot to mention. You can add this line in your `routes.rb`, just before you mount the sidekiq web interface (`mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'`).